# Using C# WebBrowser within app

Tags: c#, hyperlink, webbrowser-control

I'm pretty terrible at c# but have been tasked to created a app that allows people you join a queue or be removed from a queue. 
All it really is, is a hyperlink that determines if someone is in the queue or not. Below is the code i created so if the user click on the button it opens up Firefox and directs them to a page that replies with 'OK'.
This works perfectly however not everyone has Firefox installed and not everyone has a 32/64 bit machine so the directory where Firefox is stored can be different meaning i have to create this app user specific. 
Reason for using Firefox is down to  the actual hyperlink as it doesn't work on any other browser iv tested (ie,chrome)

What i would like to do is add the c# web browser on the app so when someone clicks on the button it will show in the web browser 'OK'
Really what im asking is how do i call the c# web browser rather than Fire Fox.
Thanks

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/agent/unpause.json?active_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&active_user=xxxxx&username=VOIP&password=xxxxxx&client=snom");
        BtnQue.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
        BtnDND.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just open that URL directly (HttpWebRequest for example) without using a Browser at all? Thats how one would usually interact with an API.

Comment: Hi Alex I thought the only way i could do it was by opening a brower im not sure how i would do a HttpWebRequest

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx  Plug in your url to the sample and see what happens

Comment: Hi Alex I have tried the webRequest but that doesnt work. It would appear that i would need to use a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating an app using Windows Forms, there is an inbuilt web browser, that you can drag onto the Form designer and then can it load a page by executing:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(URL);
```

either by clicking a button, or just executing it.

The Form designer allows you to make a simple browser that automatically opens specific site, or prompts the user for ID and password, before opening the link with the specified ID and password.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach (I guess) is to use a WebClient as it follows:

```
var myWebClient = new WebClient();
var URI = " "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/agent/unpause.json?active_....";
myWebClient.navigate(URI);
```

Then you can see the response HTML.

If you want to open it in a browser you can delegate it and open in the default webbrowser like this:

```
var URI = " "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/agent/unpause.json?active_....";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(URI);
```